# SyntaxError: Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make my first discord bot and I have run into an error that I just don't understand so if someone could please explain to me why this doesn't work.
This is the code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const token = 'token';
const prefix = '%';
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('stonks is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'koji'){
        message.channel.send('kurac!');
    } else if (command == 'nastran'){
        message.channel.send('Alejandro Hkavsc Nastran je legenda!');
    } else if (command == 'egart'){
        message.channel.send('Egart je šved');
    } else if (command == 'play')
        let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

        switch (args[0]) {
            case 'play':
                function play(connection, message){
                  var server = servers[message.guild.id];

                  server.dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(server.queue[0], {filter: "audioonly"}));
                  server.queue.shift();

                  server.dispatcher.on("end", function(){
                      if(server.queue[0]){
                          play(connection, message);
                      }else {
                          connection.disconnect();
                      }
                  });
                }

            if(!args[1]){
                message.channel.send("you need to provide a link");
                return;
            }

            if(!message.member.voice.channel){
                message.channel.send("you must be in a voice channel to play the bot");
                return;
            }

            if(!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                queue: []
            }

            var server = servers[message.guild.id];
            server.queue.push(args[1]);

            if(!message.member.voice.connection) message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(function(connection){
                play(connection, message);
            }) 

            break;
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

Answer (score 4):

That means you can't declare a `let` variable in a single statement context.

```js
} else if (command == 'play')
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
```

Instead, you must add brackets to make it a multiple statement context.

```js
} else if (command == 'play') {
 let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
 // ...
}
```